# Granite top loosing shine and looks like cloudy

Tags: kitchen-counters, granite

Our granite is a dark colored(it is granite and not imitation, not sure of the exact details though). We use 409 granite and steel for cleaning every day. I did the granite sealant a month ago after 6 months(bought house a year ago). Lately the granite started to loose its shine and looks cloudy with water marks after cleaning. What kind of care should I take at this point to keep the granite look shiny and clean? Should I polish it? Find the image of the granite below. It looks better in the pics than outside.

[image]

Comment: Do you remove the residue of 409 by wiping with a rag with only warm water?

Comment: @JimStewart nope didn't know that. I will try that